# Finding Javascript-Applied Inline Styles to Debug Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

**SCENARIO:** I am taking over management of a website where the former web developer has unfortunately spread out many relevant functions over many long JS files. It is hard for me to find where an inline CSS style is coming from in the JS or what function is applying this style directly to the element.

**QUESTION:** Is there a method of reverse engineering an element's inline styles to see where they are coming from?

Comment: I know this is like asking to see the eggs of a cake that is already baked. But I'm hopeful that there is a way.

Comment: Use your browsers development tools

Comment: If using chrome,  Ctrl+Alt+i (on windows),  select the element who style you want to look up,  see the styles panel exactly where it comes from

Comment: @LDMS If using Chrome, how could I use the inspector to do that?

Comment: I'll post some screenshots

Comment: if code has used jQuery then try to find .css function in javascript

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the JS part,  it's quite a bit more complicated then.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A possible way is to add a DOM breakpoint in Chrome Dev Tools

[image]

For that to work, you have to add the breakpoint before the style is added. That can be tricky, but you can force a breakpoint before loading any JavaScript by adding the following immediately after the HTML element in question

```
<script>debugger</script>
```

Try it on the following code

- Click on the "Run Code Snippet" button below
- Open Dev Tools
- Right click the paragraph
- Select Break On... ->  Attribute modifications
- Click the "Add border color" button
- Voila, your debugger stops at the code that is modifying the style

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
         document.querySelector('p').style.border = '2px solid red';    
    });
}
```

```html
<p> Sample Paragraph </p>
<button>Add border color</button>
```

Comment: Tip: Set a single `Subtree Modifications` DOM breakpoint on a top-level node, like the `body`, and a breakpoint will get triggered whenever any of its children are modified.

Comment: @KayceBasques Not sure it's a good idea, you will get flooded with breakpoints. For this question, the OP wants to know specifically when a specific element is about to be modified. Your suggestion may be valid in other contexts but not for this question as asked. From the OP `an inline CSS style is coming from in the JS or what function is applying this style directly to the element.`

Comment: @JuanMendes Right. Depends on the context. It's useful when you don't have a lot of nodes getting modified, though.

Comment: But what to do, if the element is 'styled' at the very load of the page? All DOM breakpoints are reset in this case...

Comment: @VadimAnisimov You didn't read the full answer? `For that to work, you have to add the breakpoint before the style is added. That can be tricky, but you can force a breakpoint before loading any JavaScript by adding the following immediately after the HTML element in question <script>debugger</script>`