# How do I find the origin source of an element.style? i.e. Which JS or jQ file is injecting it. I want to fix, not override

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, inline, elementstyle

The styles in question are not hardcoded into the HTML or CSS. They're being dynamically added in through either a JS or jQ file. I run into this all the time. I always end up just reading through all of the files until I find it. Is there a faster way using dev tools? 
I do ***not*** want to override it with an `!important` tag, I want to find the origin and fix it.

Some people are pointing out this solution:
[Finding Javascript-Applied Inline Styles to Debug Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657953/finding-javascript-applied-inline-styles-to-debug-javascript)
But this doesn't answer my question, as this shows you the code snippet causing the problem, but I'm looking for the source file name and/or path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Javascript-Applied Inline Styles to Debug Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657953/finding-javascript-applied-inline-styles-to-debug-javascript)

Comment: DOM breakpoints, as mentioned, as probably your best bet. Tip: Set a single `Subtree Modifications` DOM breakpoint on a top-level node, like the `body`, and a breakpoint will get triggered whenever any of its children are modified.

Comment: The answer that is linked does answer the question, if you follow the instructions, the debugger will stop on the file making the change and it will say its full path if you move your mouse over the tab name (that has the file name)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to find what styles are applied by using Chrome Devtools. In Chrome, if you right click on an element and "inspect," then view the styles in the "Computed" tab then you should see what styles are affecting the element.

[image: example of computed tab]

If you're looking for the injected javascript, try this [previously asked question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657953/finding-javascript-applied-inline-styles-to-debug-javascript). Here, Chrome Devtools DOM breakpoint is used to find the css.

Example image:
[image]

After DevTools sends you to the "sources" tab it shows the first file that executes. However, if you click on the "Call Stack" drop down menu, it will show you all the affecting files, and if you click through them you can find the one causing the problem. When you get to the right file, DevTools will highlight the code that is affecting the page.

Comment: Thanks! The problem I'm seeing though is that the styles affecting the element are not coming from a CSS file. They're being dynamically added to the inline level by either a JS or jQ file. Devtools doesn't tell you which file is doing it though. (or maybe it does...that's what I'm asking for).

Comment: @desanddev it does tell you. If you are on the 'computed' tab, click the style you want to find and the file source will be displayed.

Comment: I added an image to show you what I mean. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you show an example where the style was injected by javascript?

Comment: No, this is not correct.  **This does not show you where in the javascript the style came from**.  OP wants to know - when a style is injected by js, how to find where that is being injected.

Comment: @cale_b I see now, I added a link to my answer that might be a little more specifically what you're looking for. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: @Robotnicka Unfortunately, when the styles added through JS or jQ it doesn't tell you the source here, it just says "element.style". Here's a screenshot http://imgur.com/Kl7x1SF

Comment: @cale_b you're right, thanks for clarifying that for me!

Comment: @desanddev check the last link in my answer, it has some instructions on finding it via Chrome Devtools DOM breakpoints. I'm hopeful that it will be what you need! :)

Comment: @Robotnicka from what I can tell, that method is only showing you the code snippet that's causing it. I'm trying to find the source file that it's coming from, similar to your first screenshot which shows the name of the CSS file it's coming from - only this one is for JS. That's an interesting technique though, thanks for sharing that! I can see it coming in handy for other situations. I actually wouldn't be able to do that on this project anyway though, because our CMS won't let you add <script> tags into the middle of page content - only into the <head>, after the <body>, or before </body>.

Comment: @desanddev it should show you the sourcefile in the Sources tab, when you run the DOM debugger. I'll paste the screenshot into my answer.

Comment: As far as not being able to add script tags, just edit the html directly in  devtools. Right click the element in the 'element' tab, and click "Edit as HTML", you can add a <script>debugger</script> directly in the website to test it out.

Comment: I got the method you sent me to work! There's an additional step I had to take that wasn't in the tutorial. After it sends me to the "sources" tab it doesn't show me the file that's causing the problem - it's showing the first file that executes. However, if I click on the "Call Stack" drop down menu, it will show me all the affecting files, and if I click through them I can find the one causing the problem. When I get to the right file, it even highlights the code that is affecting the page. @Robotnicka

Comment: @Robotnicka Thank you for this lead! If you want to write this step in your post, or mention my last comment, I can mark it Solved.

Comment: @Robotnicka: Hey.. can you please add after elaborating a bit - your comment about directly adding <script>debugger</script> in the website to test... I am going through the same issue and trying to figure out the source file causing the element.style...